# Is there a way to save current filtering before refreshing DataGridView, then reapplying it?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, filtering

I am wanting to save current column filtering (filtering done within the DataGridView, NOT programmatically) before refreshing a DataGridView, so that after the refresh I can reapply the same filtering.

I have looked on this site and others. I have also Googled the issue. What I am finding is people asking about filtering done programmatically, not filtering done using the built-in filtering within the DataGridView.

I am also finding that many people confuse filtering with sorting. Saving the sorting is easily enough - I am looking for saving/reapplying the filtering.

EDIT: As Oak_3260548 pointed out, I am using a 3rd party control - ADGV.AdvancedDataGridView.

Comment: What do you mean by *filtering* `DataGridView`? There's no filtering in Winform default `DataGridView`. Perhaps you have a 3rd party control or other type of control?

Comment: Oak_3260548 thanks for the response! I edited my original post. I am using ADGV.AdvancedDataGridView.

Comment: If it's the one from GitHub from David Egironi, I'd suggest to post an issue on the project page: https://github.com/davidegironi/advanceddatagridview/issues. The author might give you the most credible answer. Unfortunately, I don't know anything about this ADGV. A bit off topic: I always preferer to use the very basic controls over 3rd party produced and it is not difficult at all to do filtering of datagridview. It doesn't need implementation and it's stable as rock. Particularly, for filtering I use `ToolStrip` above DGV, with `TextBoxes` and `ComboBoxes` set to the width of columns...